# how to read SD card data in android mobile application?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-mobile, flex4.6

I am building an android mobile application in Flex 4.5, Which will read some data from SD card and display data in container like image. But i am not able to access SD card in flex mobile application. Please provide me solution for, how can i access SD card data in flex mobile application?

Any web link or code sample would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is what you are looking for. 
[Write to SD](http://richard-heck.blogspot.gr/2011/01/how-to-write-file-to-android-filesystem.html)

However before checking the code you should make sure that you have setted the needed permitions correctly.

Comment: Many thanks for reply leossmith, i have followed article but it is writing in tablet internal memory not in external SD card. Still i am waiting for, how can i do it.